# How to load JSON assets into a Flutter App?

Tags: dart, flutter

How do I load a JSON asset into my Flutter app?

My `pubspec.yaml` file has the following:

```
assets:
    - assets/data.json
```

I keep getting stuck trying to load the data. I tried:

```
final json = JSON.decode(
    DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/data.json")
);
```

But I get the error:

> The argument type 'Future< String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

Comment: Apparently JSON.Decode returns a map, not a string

Comment: Yes, the end result I want is a `map` from `JSON.decode`. I'm just having trouble feeding it the string representation of the JSON file.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[@Alexandre Beaudet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5275867/alexandre-beaudet)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49758100/6045800) is correct but doesn't give a lot of context about what is going on.

When you're calling `loadString`, it's actually an asynchronous method call. You can tell because it returns a `Future<value>` rather than just a `value`. This means that it doesn't immediately have a result of String, but will at some point in the future.

There are two main ways of dealing with asynchronicity in Dart; the first being to use `async` and `await`, the second being to use the futures directly. See the [dart guide on Asynchronous Programming](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures).

If you use `future.then` directly, you can do it from a normal function (i.e. from initState etc). You simply specify the callback and in the callback what to do with the result.

```
void printDailyNewsDigest() {
  final future = gatherNewsReports();
  future.then((news) => print(news));
}
```

If you want to use `await` as @Alexandre has illustrated, you need to mark the function you are using it from as `async`, i.e.:

```
Future<Void> printDailyNewsDigest() async {
  String news = await gatherNewsReports();
  print(news);
}
```

If you override a function (i.e. initState) you also need to make sure you don't change the return value. That should get caught by dart 2's typing most of the time, but void -> Future doesn't seem to be.

One last thing to note - if you're using the result of the data to build widgets, you'll probably want to look at using a [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

Comment: Was in a rush yesterday, thanks for putting some explanations and context !

Answer (score 120):

Try out :

```
String data = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/data.json");
final jsonResult = jsonDecode(data); //latest Dart
```

Comment: I also like `json_serializable`'s approach. Doesn't need to include that json as asset in the `pubspec.yaml` at all.

Comment: I had to declare the assets/data.json in my pubspec.yaml otherwise the file was not be found, using Flutter 3.x.

Answer (score 39):

I use the following to parse json in assets:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
//...
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> parseJsonFromAssets(String assetsPath) async {
    print('--- Parse json from: $assetsPath');
    return rootBundle.loadString(assetsPath)
        .then((jsonStr) => jsonDecode(jsonStr));
  }
```

Usage async:

```
parseJsonFromAssets(path)
    .then((dmap) => {
    // here you get json `dmap` as Map<String, dynamic>
    print(dmap);
}));
```

Usage sync:

```
Map<String, dynamic> dmap = await parseJsonFromAssets('assets/test.json');
```

Comment: Dear thunder Why String jsonString = await _loadAStudentAsset();
              final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
               return chiese.fromJson(jsonResponse[0]); give me only first row of json ..i can't retrive all rows ??

Comment: @DanieleAngelini Does your Json string contains `\n` or any thing like it? And where do u get the first row? `jsonResponse` or `jsonResponse[0]` ?

Comment: Dear thundertrick can look here https://flutterforum.co/t/cannot-read-entire-file-to-parse-json/778 i post all my code... thx ...i'm stuck!!!

Comment: @DanieleAngelini It seems u r parsing a json array, which might not be supported. Try to add the array to a json, such as `{"data":[{},{}]}`

Answer (score 38):

You can use this code :)

```
loadJson() async {
  String data = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/keyboard.json');
  jsonResult = json.decode(data);
  print(jsonResult);
}
```

Can load on start :)

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      await loadJson();
    });
  }
```

Need to add the JSON on the asset

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/json/keyboard.json
```