# Error when trying to retrieve data from last entry of JSON file

Tags: android, json, flutter, runtime-error

I'm trying read a JSON file and take a value from the last entry to display on screen when the Widget is built. The JSON file is stored locally and it's been added to pubspec.yaml. Every time I go the my test page to see if the value is being displayed, I get the error screenshot below. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

This is my PODO:

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<HistoryData> historyDataFromJson(String str) => List<HistoryData>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => HistoryData.fromJson(x)));

String historyDataToJson(List<HistoryData> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class HistoryData {
  HistoryData({
      this.date,
      this.weight,
      this.loss,
      this.change,
  });

  String date;
  String weight;
  String loss;
  String change;

  factory HistoryData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => HistoryData(
      date: json["date"],
      weight: json["weight"],
      loss: json["loss"],
      change: json["change"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
      "date": date,
      "weight": weight,
      "loss": loss,
      "change": change,
  };
}
```

and this is the Widget that will create my screen:

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  String current = '';

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    current = getCurrentWeight();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text(current)
      ),
    );
  }

  String getCurrentWeight() {
    List<HistoryData> historyList = historyDataFromJson(rootBundle.loadString('json_files/history.json').toString());
    var history = historyList[historyList.length-1];
    String current = history.weight;
    return current;
  }
}
```

UPDATE:
Here's the entire JSON file, as requested.

```
[
    {
        "date" : "17/06/2020",
        "weight" : "95.0",
        "loss" : "+0.0",
        "change" : "+0.0"
    },
    {
        "date" : "18/06/2020",
        "weight" : "96.0",
        "loss" : "+1.0",
        "change" : "+1.1"
    },
    {
        "date" : "19/06/2020",
        "weight" : "95.1",
        "loss" : "-0.9",
        "change" : "-0.9"
    },
    {
        "date" : "20/06/2020",
        "weight" : "94.2",
        "loss" : "-0.9",
        "change" : "-0.9"
    },
    {
        "date" : "21/06/2020",
        "weight" : "92.0",
        "loss" : "-2.2",
        "change" : "-2.3"
    },
    {
        "date" : "22/06/2020",
        "weight" : "90.6",
        "loss" : "-1.4",
        "change" : "-1.5"
    },
    {
        "date" : "23/06/2020",
        "weight" : "89.6",
        "loss" : "-1.0",
        "change" : "-1.1"
    },
    {
        "date" : "24/06/2020",
        "weight" : "89.4",
        "loss" : "-0.2",
        "change" : "-0.2"
    },
    {
        "date" : "25/06/2020",
        "weight" : "87.8",
        "loss" : "-1.6",
        "change" : "-1.8"
    },
    {
        "date" : "26/06/2020",
        "weight" : "86.1",
        "loss" : "-1.7",
        "change" : "-1.9"
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you also show us sample JSON data?

Comment: I've added some of the data in the JSON file.

Comment: can you post the complete JSON file? Looks like something is wrong with the JSON data, kind of incomplete or invalid characters

Comment: I've updated the post with the entire JSON file I'm using. There shouldn't be an issue with it as I've successfully created a ListView with it on another screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rootBundle.loadString()` returns a `Future` like the error implies. Then you're doing `toString` on that, which is `Instance of ...`, leading to your specific error as that is not a JSON.

You need to `await` the result of `rootBundle.loadString('json_files/history.json')`:

```dart
Future<String> getCurrentWeight() async {
  List<HistoryData> historyList = historyDataFromJson(await rootBundle.loadString('json_files/history.json'));
  var history = historyList[historyList.length-1];
  String current = history.weight;
  return current;
}
```

Then you have to modify your widget to properly handle display this future data with `FutureBuilder`.

```dart
class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  Future<String> current;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    current = getCurrentWeight();//Obtain your future
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: current,//Pass the future
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData) {//Show data only when it's available
          return Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(snapshot.data)//Obtain data here
            ),
          );
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();//Show this otherwise
      }
    );
  }

  Future<String> getCurrentWeight() async {
    List<HistoryData> historyList = historyDataFromJson(await rootBundle.loadString('json_files/history.json'));
    var history = historyList[historyList.length-1];
    String current = history.weight;
    return current;
  }
}
```

Comment: You beat me to the answer! Thanks anyway, and I appreciate the error explanation. I found this post with the answers, it gives a little more detail for anyone that finds it useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49757953/how-to-load-json-assets-into-flutter-app.